# Android app crashes on screen orientation change

Tags: android, onconfigurationchanged

I'm developing an application which will support multiple screens. I have created three layouts (large, small, medium). I'm testing it. I have two screens sign in and sign up.

In sign in it is working fine. But when I click on sign up button then I go to sign up page and if I'm in portrait mode and changes the mode the app gets crashed and there is no something like crash report in the logcat as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not added any code like `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` to your manifest, your current activity (sign up?) will restart if you change the mode. It could be that you cannot restart the activity at that point because not all the info will be available for the activity.

(btw: your question is not completely clear, but I gather that if you change mode (portrait/landscape) in a certain activity your application crashes)

Answer (score 0):

By default, android restarts your activity in case of configuration changed. You should correctly treat this restart(by saving and restoring saved instance) or as a not recommended way override [`onConfigurationChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29)() method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run you application in debug mode, in case of crash you will see exception that cause problem.

Answer (score 0):

why u used different screen for portrait n landscape , many times we can't used different screen . we written code in that way , its common for both the screens

ex. in layout parameters u used "fill_parent" for width , it is effective in both cases

In your case , you make signin and signup form,i m also make a signin and signup form and 
i don't feel to make different layouts or screen.

I suggest that make common screen for both Mode.

Comment: The code can (and should) be common, but it _is_ correct to have different layouts for portrait/landscape, and low/medium/high density screens. The exception would be if the usability of the layout is truly not impaired by orientation (possible, for simple layouts) or density (possible, if you've taken care to accommodate different screen densities)